# Flink statefun and confluent schema registry compatibility

Tags: confluent-schema-registry, flink-statefun

I'm trying to egress to confluent kafka from flink statefun. In [confluent git repo](https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/5.5.0-post/clients/avro/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/clients/basicavro/ProducerExample.java)
in order to schema check and put data to kafka topic all we need to do is use kafka client ProducerRecord object with avro object.

But in [statefun](https://github.com/apache/flink-statefun/blob/master/statefun-examples/statefun-greeter-example/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/statefun/examples/greeter/GreetingIO.java) we need to override "ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> serialize" method for kafka egress. This causes the following error.

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error registering Avro schema: "bytes"
```

Schema registery and statefun kafka egress seem to be incompatible. Are there any workaround ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use Confluent Schema Registry with Statefun Egress.

In order to do so, you first register your schema manually with the schema registry and then supply `KafkaEgressSerializer` a `byte[]` serialized by  `KafkaAvroSerializer` instance.

Code below is the gist of it and is in compliance with the first one in Igal's workaround suggestions:

```
public class SpecificRecordFromAvroSchemaSerializer implements KafkaEgressSerializer<SpecificRecordGeneratedFromAvroSchema> {

    private static String KAFKA_TOPIC = "kafka_topic";

    private static CachedSchemaRegistryClient schemaRegistryClient = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(
        "http://schema-registry:8081",
        1_000
    );
    private static KafkaAvroSerializer kafkaAvroSerializer = new KafkaAvroSerializer(schemaRegistryClient);

    static {
        try {
            schemaRegistryClient.register(
                KAFKA_TOPIC + "-value", // assuming subject name strategy is TopicNameStrategy (default)
                SpecificRecordGeneratedFromAvroSchema.getClassSchema()
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RestClientException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> serialize(SpecificRecordGeneratedFromAvroSchema specificRecordGeneratedFromAvroSchema) {
        byte[] valueData = kafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(
            KAFKA_TOPIC,
            specificRecordGeneratedFromAvroSchema
        );

        return new ProducerRecord<>(
            KAFKA_TOPIC,
            String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()).getBytes(),
            valueData
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Schema registry is not directly supported at this version of stateful functions,
but few workarounds are possible:

1. Connect to the schema registry by your self from the `KafkaEgressSerializer` class. In your linked example that would need to be happening [here](https://github.com/apache/flink-statefun/blob/master/statefun-examples/statefun-greeter-example/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/statefun/examples/greeter/GreetingIO.java#L93).
2. Provide your own instance of a FlinkKafkaProducer that is based [on](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/kafka.html#the-deserializationschema) (see
   `AvroDeserializationSchema`)
3. Mange the schemas outside of stateful functions, but serialize your Avro record to bytes. Make sure to remove the schema registry from the properties that being passed to the `KafkaProducer`